# Convert similar names to figures

Tags: r, excel, statistics

I have different genotypes which their pedigree has a lot of parents for example

```
genotypes parents
G1        mac cemolt giza
G2        mac miser
G3        misr cemolt mac NE10
```

I have a lot of genotypes I would like to make a matrix which include the common parents between each two genotypes, so it should look like

```
   G1 G2 G3
G1 0   1  2
G2        2
```

How can I perform this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using reproducible code and nested sapplys for the intersect function.

```
genotypes <- c("G1", "G2", "G3")
parents <- list(c("mac", "cemolt", "giza"), c("mac", "miser"),
             c("miser", "cemolt", "mac", "NE10"))

comparisons <- sapply(parents, function(x) 
    sapply(parents, function(y) length(intersect(x,y))))
rownames(comparisons) <- genotypes
colnames(comparisons) <- genotypes

as.dist(comparisons)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Generate data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(genotypes = c("G1", "G2", "G3"),
                       parents = c("mac cemolt giza",
                                   "mac miser",
                                   "miser cemolt mac NE10"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

2) Write function to find common parents within genotype strings.

*Assumptions:* In the parents column, each parent is separated by a space. If a genotype is compared to itself, return 0 common parents (based on your expected result table).

```
commonParents <- function(vector1, vector2) {
    lapply(1:length(vector1), function(x) {
        if(vector1[x] == vector2[x]) {
            return(0)
        } else {
            parents <- unlist(strsplit(vector1[x], split = " "))
            sum(sapply(parents, function(y) grepl(y, vector2[x], ignore.case = TRUE)))   
        }
    })
}
```

3) Use `outer` to create a matrix of the values:

```
outer(df$parents, df$parents, FUN = "commonParents")
```